# Wrong word boundaries in nginx files with vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using the nginx syntax file with vim from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1886). Whenever I edit files of type `nginx` i get strange word boundaries. For example, if i have this line:

```
root /www/www.some-example.com/htdocs/www;
^    ^             ^
```

And press `w`, the cursor jumps to the positions indicated by `^`. I would rather expect it to be

```
root /www/www.some-example.com/htdocs/www;
^     ^   ^   ^    ^       ^   ^      ^
```

which is what i get in non-nginx files.

My `iskeyword` is:

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.,/,:
```

From the syntax file i could not find where this behavior would be changed. So how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `'iskeyword'` is changed in that syntax script on line 8, 9 and 10:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=.
setlocal iskeyword+=/
setlocal iskeyword+=:
```

Comment out these three lines to fix your issue.

Comment: Oops, indeed. Totally missed that. I wonder what's the idea behind that.